# How to use google autocomplete and google traffic layer map api

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I am trying to use google autocomplete places and traffic layer map. 
I am including **libraries=places** and **callback=initMap** with api key but autocomplete is not working. If I remove callback=initMap then autocomplete is working but with callback=initMap autocomplete is not working and only traffic layer map is showing. Thank you in advance.

```
<style>
#map {
    height: 500px;
}
</style>


<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="location" onFocus="initialize()" id="autocomplete">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" >
</form>


<div id="map"></div><!--Traffic Map-->

<?php
$lat = '';
$long = '';
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $address = urlencode($_POST['location']);
    $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address";
    $geocode = file_get_contents($url);
    $output = json_decode($geocode);
    if ($output->status == "OK") 
    {
        $lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
    }
    else{
        echo $output->status;
    }
}
?>


<script><!--AutoComplete-->
    var autocomplete;
    function initialize() {
      autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
         (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
          { types: ['geocode'] });
      google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
      });
    }
</script>


<script><!--TrafficLayer-->
function initMap() 
{
 var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat;  ?>, <?php echo $long; ?>),
    zoom: 12,
    scrollwheel: true,
    draggable: true,
    panControl: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    scaleControl: true,
    streetViewControl: true,
    overviewMapControl: true,
    rotateControl: true,
  };

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),mapOptions);

var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
        trafficLayer.setMap(map);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position:{lat: <?php echo $lat;  ?>, lng: <?php echo $long; ?>},
        map:map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    }); 
}
</script>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
<!--<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting the code (for autocomplete purposes) inside initMap(), after you build the map.

kind of like this:

```
var autocomplete;
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
     (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
      { types: ['geocode'] });
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
  });
```

after you declare

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position:{lat: <?php echo $lat;  ?>, lng: <?php echo $long; ?>},
    map:map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
});
```

Comment: Tried it but still not working.

Comment: can you add info about the error that you get, also what are you trying to do here:  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
  }); ?

Comment: What I am trying to do is, when I type location name inside the form input box then I get suggestion of the  address. Then after selecting the address and submitting the form map with traffic layer generates of that submitted location.

Comment: When I only include libraries=places with api key(<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>), then 
 places autocomplete function is working fine. But when I include callback=initMap with libraries=place(<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>), then the autocomplete place function is not working.